# How do I use a custom keyboard layout created with Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout

Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC) (v1.4) is not officially compatible with Windows 8. Some report that it works anyway but I cannot confirm that and there are other reports on the net that have the same problem. Because there seem to be several similar scenarios, let me be specific about the one I'm talking about here:

I'm on a Windows 8.1 machine (64 bit) and I have a custom keyboard layout created with MSKLC on my Windows 7 machine. When running the `setup.exe` on the Win8 machine, the keyboard layout seemed to install smoothly, just like on Win7.

The next step is to add the custom layout to whichever input language you want to use it with. That also works fine (although there is a foreboding because the preview doesn't work, it's greyed out). But the real problem comes after this: you wont find your new layout in the language bar and you wont be able to select it with the default keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>.

So the question is: is there a way to use the custom layout anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to use the MSKLC custom layout in Windows 8.1. It's not more than a workaround, I'd say, but it works:

Go to *Control Panel* → *Language* → *Advanced Settings*

Under *Switching input methods* select *Options* and then *Advanced Key Settings*

Here you can assign a shortcut that directly activates your custom keyboard layout (in combination with a language, so if you want to use the same layout with different languages, you need one shortcut for each combination in order to swap between these).

BTW: I suspect that the reason, why some people report that MSKLC works with Windows 8 is that they have only one keyboard layout or one language installed so that the system automatically uses the custom layout and hence there is no need for all of the above.

Comment: Does it work with simple Windows 8 (not 8.1)?

Comment: Since I have 8.1, I can't tell for sure, but I see no reason why it shouldn't. The update to 8.1 is free by the way. No need to stay on 8.0...

Comment: Thanks! I know the update is free. But to spend half a day doing back-up, resinstalling the OS, reinstalling all the programmes etc. may be an overkill when the goal is just to get some keyboard layout working.

Answer (score 0):

> you wont find your new layout in the language bar and you wont be able to select it

In my case I just had to reboot my computer. Relogin may also help but I would reboot the computer.

Preview will be still gray but layout will start working and also will be added to the list.

Second time it worked without reboot.